# Clustering 'Like' records yii2

Tags: mysql, sorting, gridview, yii2

i am attempting to create a table for my client that has a bunch of records of a type, and i need to create a record of a 'child' type which inherits most of its fields from its parent, and that i have done.

now i need to use Gridview to display that information but the child records need to be clustered near the parent, so its like;

```
    -parent record 1
     -child record 1
     -child record 2
    -parent record 2
    -parent record 3
    -parent record 4
     -child record 1
     -child record 2
    etc etc...
```

right now i am using

```
 $dataProvider->sort = ['defaultOrder' => ['sort_by_this_column'=>SORT_DESC]];
```

and i have a flag that's set for the child records 'is_child', as well as having the parents id stored in a column called 'parent_id'

is there any way to cluster these records together using only sorting?

i can't use an interface component here, because my client needs this to be searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a sort order like:

`order by CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN id ELSE parent_id END ASC, id ASC`

If indeed the id of the parent is lower then it's children, then the parent will show first.

Comment: I ended up adding the reference ID to the parent as well so “parent_id = id” on parent and parent_id = parent->id on the child, then ordered by my sorting column, then by parent_id, then by id. So it’d group by my custom sort, then by the common parent Id, and then order them from oldest to newest.